# Deleting DataFrames from List Based On Conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, neural-network

Good evening,

May I please get help with a Python problem I have? I have a large .csv file (21,600,000 rows deep, 6 columns wide). The data is divided up into groups of 1000 rows each (so we have 21,600 data groups). I wish to delete whole groups based on whether certain rows contain a large value (-3.4*10^38) that appears from time to time. I wrote the following Python script:

```
# CALL-IN LIBRARIES
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import logging

os.chdir('/media/Maps/test_runs/') #Set file directory.
map_data='map_combined.csv'

maps1 = pd.read_csv(coasts_data, header=None, encoding='latin1')

#Combine all data into a single frame

frames = [maps1] 
df = pd.concat(frames)

#### Arrange data so that each LoS vector of 1000 pts is in a single row #####

n = 1000  #chunk row size
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]

ind = 0
l=[]
for index,frame in enumerate(list_df):
        vals = frame[df.iloc[:,2]].values
        if np.all(vals > -100000):
             l.append(index)
for x in sorted(l, reverse=True):
    del list_df[x]
```

I tried to break the .csv file into a list of DataFrames, then apply a condition upon each DataFrame (delete any DataFrame that contains values less -100000, the extraneous values being in column 2 of the data). However, the script simply crashes Spyder with no error messages presented.

As a check, the final product should be a .csv with a row count divisible by 1000 (it's going into a neural network with 1000 node input layer, thus the need to avoid partial data sets).

Any advice or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the error message you get when trying to run the code. I've identified one syntax error that would be at least part of the problem.

Comment: I wish I could. The is is that when I run the code in Spyder (Anaconda-Navigator) it simply crashes and closes out, I don't get an error message per se.

Comment: In that case, can you try copying and pasting each line of code in, one at a time, to see which line causes the error?

Comment: The error seems to begin with the For-Loop. I commented it out, and I don't get any crashing.

Comment: Can you try `for index,frame in enumerate(list_df):` `pass` and comment out the rest. Then go through and uncomment each line in the for loop, and if you have an empty for loop, add a line with `pass`.

Comment: It didn't crash after I added the above code, it actually did finish (I commented out the code following it). I noticed that the next line, "vals" crashed though (I also had to remove its indent).

Comment: Try and change it to `vals = frame.iloc[:,2].values`

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore, I notice that "vals" now gives what looks like the last 1000 rows of the dataset.

Comment: I think I get what should be happening now, I've updated my answer to hopefully fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid line of code:

```py
if <-100000 not in vals:
```

Instead, use this:

```py
if np.any(vals < -100000):
```

Edit: I think I now understand your use case - try the following:

```py
l=[]
for index, frame in enumerate(list_df):
    vals = frame.iloc[:,2].values
    # if any values in this part of the frame are wrong, store index for deletion
    if np.any(vals < -100000):
         l.append(index)
for x in sorted(l, reverse=True):
    del list_df[x]
```

Comment: I swapped in the code you suggested. You are right, the initial code wasn't correct, though I just crashed Spyder again when I ran it again. I feel their is something else about the code that is causing this.

Comment: Could you update your code in the question with your new code, and also post the error message you're getting?

Comment: Will do, give me a minute to copy it over.

Comment: It worked! It now seems to be deleting the bad data from the original data set. I wanted to add, by adding the term "df1 = pd.concat(list_df)" at the very end (not inside the for-loop, outside it) I was able to recombine the now "clean" DataFrames into one DataFrame. Problem solved. Thank you!  :)